# React Hooks - Ref is not available inside useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am using ReactHooks. I am trying to access `ref` of `User` component in `useEffect` function, but I am getting `elRef.current` value as `null`, though I passed `elRef.current` as second argument to `useEffect`.  I am supposed to get reference to an element, but outside (function body) of `useEffect`, `ref` value is available. Why is that ? How can I get `elRef.current` value inside `useEffect`?

**code**

```
import React, { Component, useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";

const useFetch = url => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(
    () => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      fetch(url)
        .then(response => {
          if (!response.ok) throw Error(response.statusText);
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(json => {
          setIsLoading(false);
          setData(json.data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          setIsLoading(false);
          setError(error);
        });
    },
    [url]
  );

  return { data, isLoading, error };
};

const User = ({ id }) => {
  const elRef = useRef(null);
  const { data: user } = useFetch(`https://reqres.in/api/users/${id}`);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("ref", elRef.current);
  }, [elRef.current]);
  if (!user) return null;
  return <div ref={elRef}>{user.first_name + " " + user.last_name}</div>;
};

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    userId: 1
  };

  handleNextClick = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      userId: prevState.userId + 1
    }));
  };

  handlePrevNext = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      userId: prevState.userId - 1
    }));
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={() => this.handlePrevClick()}
          disabled={this.state.userId === 1}
        >
          Prevoius
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => this.handleNextClick()}>Next</button>
        <User id={this.state.userId} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/74lrk9o38q)

Thanks !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a predictable behaviour.

As mentioned `@estus` you faced with this because first time when it's called on `componentDidMount` you're getting `null` (initial value) and get's updated only once on next `elRef` changing because, actually, reference still being the same.

If you need to reflect on every user change, you should pass `[user]` as second argument to function to make sure `useEffect` fired when user is changed.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/q7loq7q37q) is updated sandbox.

Hope it helped.

Comment: I thought `useEffect` was being invoked after the render method has already run? I don't get why it should be null.

Comment: @jayarjo Yes, you're correct. At the first render there no user until it's fetched from the server, so that's why we're getting such result.

Comment: There is the condition for rendering `null` if there no user, so the ref still being `null` as it was initialized.

Comment: Right. I missed the line where he actually returns `null` himself.

Answer (score 58):

You should use **useCallback** instead of useRef as suggested in the reactjs [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node).

> React will call that callback whenever the ref gets attached to a different node.

Replace this:

```
const elRef = useRef(null);
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("ref", elRef.current);
}, [elRef.current]);
```

with this:

```
const elRef = useCallback(node => {
    if (node !== null) {
        console.log("ref", node); // node = elRef.current
    }
}, []);
```

Comment: Nice! Strictly the useCallback hook isn't necessary for this to work, since there are no dependencies. The elRef function could be defined outside the component, and so only be created once.

Answer (score 10):

When you use a [function as a ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs), it is called with the instance when it is ready. So the easiest way to make the ref observable is to use [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) instead of [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref):

```
const [element, setElement] = useState<Element | null>(null);
return <div ref={setElement}></div>;
```

Then you can use it in dependency arrays for other hooks, just like any other `const` value:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (element) console.log(element);
}, [element]);
```

See also [How to rerender when refs change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59605067/320036).

Comment: The advantage this method has over `useCallback` is that the element can be manipulated. For example `element.scrollTop = number` works here, whereas it doesn't with `useCallback`.

Answer (score 3):

useEffect is used as both componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate, 
at the time of component mount you added a condition:

```
if (!user) return null;
return <div ref={elRef}>{user.first_name + " " + user.last_name}</div>;
```

because of the above condition at the time of mount, you don't have the user, so it returns null and div is not mounted in the DOM in which you are adding ref, so inside useEffect you are not getting elRef's current value as it is not rendered.

And on the click of next as the div is mounted in the dom you got the value of elRef.current.

Comment: we can see user name in initial render (after fetch resolved). It means user is present. `next` button for getting next user.

Comment: @REDDYPRASAD, No it's not present at the initial render, try to remove that condition, your code will crash. That means it is not rendering that div initially.

Comment: @REDDYPRASAD, if you remove that condition it will show you "Cannot read property 'first_name' of null" error

Comment: @REDDYPRASAD, you can do {!user ?  " '' : user.first_name + " " + user.last_name}, and remove the condition for user check.

Comment: Downvoted because we dont need to click next button to get user. if that is the case, how we are seeing username when page loads (without clicking next)

Comment: As @Denys Kotsur mentioned, i should pass `[user]` as second argument to solve issue.

Comment: I agree that `user` is `null` at initial. But after fetch resolved (second render) user is available and i was expecting ref to be available. its not availble because i diidnot pass user as `[user]` as second argument. its nothing to do with `next` button and your answer didnot solve my issue

Answer (score 3):

The assumption here is that `useEffect` needs to detect changes to `ref.current`, so needs to have the `ref` or `ref.current`in the dependencies list. I think this is due to `es-lint` being a bit over-pedantic.

Actually, the whole point of `useEffect` is that it guarantees not to run until the rendering is complete and the DOM is ready to go. That is how it handles side-effects.

So by the time `useEffect` is executed, we can be sure that `elRef.current` is set.

The problem with your code is that you don't run the renderer with `<div ref={elRef}...>` until after `user` is populated. So the DOM node you want `elRef` to reference doesn't yet exist. That is why you get the `null` logging - nothing to do with dependencies.

---

BTW: one possible alternative is to populate the div inside the effect hook:

```js
useEffect(
  () => {
    if(!user) return;
    elRef.current.innerHTML = `${user.first_name} ${user.last_name}`;
  }, [user]
);
...
//if (!user) return null;// Remove this line
return <div ref={elRef}></div>; //return div every time.
```

That way the `if (!user) return null;` line in the User component is unnecessary. Remove it, and `elRef.current` is guaranteed to be populated with the div node from the very beginning.

Answer (score -1):

set a useEffect on the elem's.current:

```js
  let elem = useRef();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    // ...
  }, [elem.current]);
```