# Why do functional components wrapped in forwardRef receive null refs when I use the useContext hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, react-forwardref

I have a **sidebarCart** component basically a cart component and its is wrapped in **forwardRef** hook and contains **useImperativeHandle** to pass a function up to the parent which is App. Everything was working fine until I introduced the **useContext** hook and now the refs inside **sidebarCart** are becoming null, what is this weird behavior?

The refs I'm talking about are **cartContainer**  and **pageShdowCover**
I discovered that when  stop my nodejs server this problem disappears.

Here is the **sidebarCart** component.

```
import React ,{createRef,forwardRef,useImperativeHandle,useContext,useEffect}from 'react'
import CartItem from './CartItem'
import {MyContext} from '../../Context/ProductsProvider'


const SideBarCart=forwardRef((props,ref)=>{
    const {setCart,cart} =useContext(MyContext)
    const cartContainer  = createRef()
    const pageShdowCover = createRef()

    const slideOut=e=>{
        cartContainer.current.style.right='-400px'
        pageShdowCover.current.style.opacity='0'
        setTimeout(()=>pageShdowCover.current.style.display='none', 600);
    }
    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
        slideIn(){
           pageShdowCover.current.style.display='block'
           cartContainer.current.style.right='0'
           pageShdowCover.current.style.opacity='1'
        }
    }),[pageShdowCover,cartContainer]);
 
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="pageShdowCover"  ref={pageShdowCover}  ></div>
            <div className="SideContainer cart" ref={cartContainer}>
                <div className="cart__top">
                    <h1>Cart</h1>
                   <i className="far fa-times-circle Close" onClick={slideOut}></i>  
                   <a onClick={slideOut}>x</a>
                </div>
                <div className="cart__body">  
                </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    )
})

export default SideBarCart
```

Comment: Is there any update on this? I think I'm having the same problem

Comment: Hi Zack so the solution I found for this kind of pattern where you've got a component that you want to affect an other component somewhere in the app  , first you could use redux . but the simple way is Rxjs and you can listen to an observer that you omet from component A , in my example Navbar's cart link  emits an observer that I listen to from the cart component and this is a really clean way to do these kind of interaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the `useContext` hook will result in children rerendering without the parent rerendering. Refs don't trigger rerenders when they are changed, so refs passed from the parent to children may be stale? (I think this is the answer - I may not be correct).

In summary (what worked for me): to solve the problem I was having, **just store a ref in state to trigger re-renders when a ref changes**.

===

**Explanation**

My use-case is that I have a parent component with 4 children. One of these children is a header, that I would like the siblings to be able to 'inject' controls into when they are rendered using `ReactDOM.createPortal`

```
- Parent
 - Header
 - A
 - B
 - C
```

I found that if I just used a ref, that when the ref is assigned to the DOM the parent isn't rerendered, therefore components `A`, `B`, `C` are not rerendered so they do not know about the newly assigned `ref.current` value.

I.E. The following does **NOT** work

```js
const Parent = () => {
  const ref = useRef()

  return (
   <div>
    <Header ref={el => { ref.current = el } />
    <C ref={ref} />
    <B ref={ref} />
    <C ref={ref} />
   </div>
  )
}

// A, B, C have the same signature
const A = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {createPortal(<SomeComponent />, ref.current)}
      <OtherComponent />
    </div>
  )
})
```

I found the solution to this in [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59605067/3114742) answer on StackOverflow. I came to this question because `A`, `B`, and `C` are using `useContext(...)`. Previously for me, when the state was created in `Parent` instead of using a context, the above code WAS working - probably because the parent was rerendering and leaving stale refs around or something (I think it was working 'accidentally'). i.e. the problem wasn't related to context, but rather how rerenders are triggered.

This code **DOES** work

```js
const Parent = () => {
  const [ref, setRef] = useState()

  return (
   <div>
    <Header ref={el => { setRef(el) } />
    <C ref={ref} />
    <B ref={ref} />
    <C ref={ref} />
   </div>
  )
}

// A, B, C have the same signature
const A = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {createPortal(<SomeComponent />, ref)}
      <OtherComponent />
    </div>
  )
})
```

Comment: this answer s very clear and intuitive , I can't believe  didn't think of using useState !!