# Ref is initially null, how to wait for it to have initialised the correct value?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that requires some extra margin based on the y position of another component. (can't do it with css since its out of the stack flow)

So basically I get the ref of that element and do this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
        ref.current && setHeaderHeight(ref.current.offsetHeight);
}, [ref.current]);
```

This works, but I get an es linting warning that I shouldn't put `ref.current` inside the dependency array because mutating them doesn't re-render the component.

However if I replace it with an empty dependency array, the ref is initially null and the `setHeaderHeight` doesn't run. Removing the array doesn't seem to be the solution either and will result in another linting warning.

What is the best way to make sure that the setState is done after the ref has the correct value?

Comment: If you want the component to rerender when the reference changes, you could just store the "ref" in state. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59600572/how-to-rerender-when-refs-change

Comment: Thanks, i guess that makes sense. Q: It is working with putting the ref as the dependency, does this mean that the es lint warning is incorrect? As it appears that after the ref value changes, it actually does also re-render the component.

Comment: Is the ref null due to some conditional rendering? [Things work just fine for me](https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-meadow-qfbdpb?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @moonwave99, No not in my code, but I believe a ref can always be null, because it might get called before the DOM is actually rendered. So in typescript, you need to include this conditional or it will error. More on this which is also pretty related to my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56541342/react-hooks-why-is-current-null-for-useref-hook.

Comment: @DBS, hmm the useState doesn't appear to immediately help. For some reason there seems to be a timing issue. The console log reports the correct html node, but then also says the height is 0, which is conflicting. When i add a bit of a setTimeOut it actually works... but it means that React is not syncing it correctly. Not sure what could cause this. I am using external Ionic components... maybe it's related