# Getting TypeError in react useRef() hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I was working on an app based on webRTC API , and working with useRef() hook in react, I got an error

```
Error:  TypeError: myVideo.current is undefined
    ContextProvider SocketContext.js:27
    promise callback*ContextProvider/< SocketContext.js:23
    React 5
    unstable_runWithPriority scheduler.development.js:468
    React 3
    workLoop scheduler.development.js:417
    flushWork scheduler.development.js:390
    performWorkUntilDeadline scheduler.development.js:157
    js scheduler.development.js:180
    js scheduler.development.js:645
    Webpack 21
```

and the code for context is

```
const myVideo = useRef();
//const myVideo = useRef(null);  tried this also but not solved 
  const userVideo = useRef();
  const connectionRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
      .then((currentStream) => {
        setStream(currentStream);

        myVideo.current.srcObject = currentStream;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Error ", err);
      })

    socket.on('me', (id) => setMe(id));

    socket.on('callUser', ({ from, name: callerName, signal }) => {
      setCall({ isReceivingCall: true, from, name: callerName, signal });
    });
  }, []);
```

I've tried adding myVideo || myVideo.current is useRef() dependency list.

Comment: Where is `myVideo` actually used, besides when you read it? `myVideo.current` will always be `undefined` unless you manually set it (for mutable refs) or if it's passed to a DOM element and instead set by React.

Comment: myVideo is being used in a component as a source of an video attribute

Comment: As a source, as in `src`? I can see you're trying to use it to set the video's `srcObject`, so therefore I assume you should be using the ref as `<video ref={myVideo} .../>`. If you aren't using it like that, or not in the proper way, that's where the mistake lies.

Comment: i'm using it in the way you're telling

Comment: <video 
        ref={myVideo}
        autoPlay
      />

Answer (score 0):

Looking a bit more into it, it seems like you can't properly use React-controlled refs within `useEffect`. A solution described [here](https://medium.com/@teh_builder/ref-objects-inside-useeffect-hooks-eb7c15198780) and several answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54346040/14274597) might help you further.

In short, your `useEffect` gets called before the reference gets set. Instead, use a callback as reference instead:

```js
const myVideo = useCallback(video => {
    if (!video) return; // video object no longer available
    // You now have the video object
    // either set the `srcObject` here, or store `video` to set it later
}, []);

// somewhere else
return <video ref={myVideo} ... />;
```